# Error in retrieving results from database in golang mysql

Tags: mysql, go

I am getting an error while retrieving results from database 
I am having a global database variable which is serving for the whole project
I have a test program to test the connection and retrieve a row
while i am able to connect to the database
but there is an error in retrieving the row
Here is my code

```
 //global database object for every package
 var (
     db *sql.DB
 )

 func initDatabase() bool {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:admin@/ipuscraper")
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println("Error in database connection")
       return false
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
          fmt.Println("Error in database call")
          return false
    }
    var str string
    err = db.QueryRow("Select title, date, url from datesheet_ipu order by  id DESC LIMIT 1").Scan(&str)
    if err != nil {
         fmt.Println("error in returning result")
         return false
    }
    fmt.Println(str)
    return true
 }
```

The error is shown at db.Query() line and the error is not nil
is there something wrong i am doing ?

Comment: Print the error to see what it is and post the result: `fmt.Println("Error:", err)`

Comment: will be much better if your method returns and **error** and then just print the error one time

Comment: Thank you guyz , actually i am new to this , i was actually closing the connection to database so thats why there was not results
thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution 
the problem with this was that i was scanning only one variable instead of that, i should have scanned three variables